# Remote database management from local development server

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am looking for a way to access and query my remote databases from my local server.
Something like PhpMyAdmin, but little more versatile.

So that I can feed it with databases I would like to see, store my queries (or better, if it has ways to access simple queries built in itself)

Can someone help me with such a PHP Script (or Class)?

Regards
Nikhil Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a MySQL client instead.

I have been using sqlyog's community edition for years. It has a quick startup, and allows you to connect to multiple servers at the same time.

http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

One of my favorite features is the ability to copy databases from one server to another.

( Yes, you could do this via the CLI, but having a GUI is handy. )

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to run as windows-programs, here are two suggestions:

Dbvisualizer http://www.dbvis.com/

Visual studio (even express versions) has what they call "database explorer", just install some mysql-connector that VS can handle, like odbc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has full support for mysql databases. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.msql.php. Just use the address for your remote server when opening the connection.